# Logical analysis of the sentence 「アメリカとの関係が悪くなったイランからの原油の輸入が減ると考える人などが多いためです」

Tags: grammar, translation, syntax

> アメリカとの関係が悪くなったイランからの原油の輸入が減ると考える人などが多いためです。

アメリカとの関係が悪くなったイラン: is a noun phrase. イラン is the head noun.

イランからの原油の輸入が減る: is an independent clause.

考える人などが多いためです: refers to the previous independent clause that, being bounded with the particle と, becomes an indirect quotation.

Translation: Because many people think that from Iran, being in a bad relation with USA, importation of crude oil will decrease.

Is it right? Any suggestions?
(Sorry for my bad English. I'm not a native English speaker)

Comment: Your understanding seems good to me. "Because many people think that imports of crude oil from Iran -- whose relationship with America has deteriorated -- will decrease". Though I have no idea what the Iran-America relationship has got to do with Japanese imports from Iran.

Comment: Well excluding that tame at the end, because I don't know what to do with it, I'd say it's more "There are many people who think that because of Iran, whose relation with America is deteriorating, the import of crude oil will decrease."

Comment: @4thDimension イラン**から**の原油の輸入: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you. Are you suggesting that this から means "because of".  I thought that it could only work like that after a predicate. Also the の after から seems to get in the way of this interpretation.

Comment: ^ そうですね、 the から in イランからの原油の輸入 means "from", not "because of".

Comment: `Though I have no idea what the Iran-America relationship has got to do with Japanese imports from Iran.` -- 日本はアメリカと同盟国で仲良しだ（と一応日本人は思ってる）からね・・

Comment: Your translation is also missing the import of `悪くなった` --> "became worse"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. (Context: the price of oil is high.) The basic structure here is

> ...と考える人などが多いためです．
>
> This is because there are many people who think ....

(I omitted the "など" for I wasn't able to embed it in the translation.)

What they think is

> アメリカとの関係が悪くなったイランからの原油の輸入が減る

which can further be decomposed into

> [アメリカとの関係が悪くなった]イランからの輸入が減る
>
> Import from Iran, whose relationship with  the U.S. has worsened, will decrease

(So [user3856370](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/7944/user3856370)'s translation in the [comment](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60560/#comment105374_60560) is sufficient.)

As for the reason why Iran-US relationship has anything to do with Japan is  that we might follow the US's policy regarding such foreign relationships, for the U.S. is one of the most fundamental ally to Japan.

Comment: I decided to post as a community wiki as the question was already solved in the comment.